# Screen scrape text with Html Agility Pack from Google Search Featured Snippets Url result

Tags: c#, screen-scraping, html-agility-pack, google-rich-snippets

I'm trying to figure out, if it is legal and possible to get result from `Google Search` [Featured Snippets](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/9351707?p=featured_snippets&hl=en-GE&visit_id=637421026152985493-3064555922&rd=1) for personal non-commercial desktop application for free, without using `Google Search API`, to parse such results:

```
string inputUrl = "http://google.com/search?q=" + "who is Elvis Presley";
```

or:

```
 string inputUrl = "http://google.com/search?search?client=firefox-b-d&q=who+is+elvis+presley";
```

I'm trying to use `HtmlAgilityPac` in `C#` `WinForms` desktop application:

```
string inputUrl = "http://somesite.net/";
```

let's say with adding result in list:

```
 List<string> outputList = new List<string>();
```

I can screen scrape links  `ExtractHref(inputUrl);`, but instead I'm trying to figure out, how to get only text words and sentences from url:

```
    private void ExtractHref(string URL)
    {
        lst.Clear();
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc = web.Load(URL);

        foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
        {
            HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];

            if (att.Value.Contains("a"))
            {                   
                outputList .Add(att.Value);                   
            }
        }

        textBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, outputList); 
    }
```

My goal is to get Google search browser result: [https://www.google.com/search?search?client=firefox-b-d&q=who+is+elvis+presley](https://www.google.com/search?search?client=firefox-b-d&q=who%20is%20elvis%20presley) shows Featured Snippets search:

> Elvis Presley, in full Elvis Aaron Presley or Elvis Aron Presley (see
> Researcher's Note), (born January 8, 1935, Tupelo, Mississippi,
> U.S.—died August 16, 1977, Memphis, Tennessee), American popular
> singer widely known as the “King of Rock and Roll” and one of rock
> music's dominant performers from the mid-1950s until ..

And topic from Wikipedia:

> Elvis Aaron Presley, also known simply as Elvis, was an American
> singer, musician and actor. He is regarded as one of the most
> significant cultural icons of the 20th century and is often referred
> to as the "King of Rock and Roll" or simply "the King".

Answer (score 0):

you just need to update for loop to read href value, since XPath already filters the `<a>` elements no further checks requried.

```
    HtmlNode[] nodes = doc.DocumentNode
            .SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
            .ToArray();
        foreach (HtmlNode item in nodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.InnerHtml);
        }
        List<string> outputList = new List<string>();

        foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='rc']"))
        {
            outputList.Add(link.InnerText);
        }
```

Comment: Hello, I have edited my question to clarify, the `link.InnerHtml` returns only link text

Comment: updated code I think this would give you list of words in the url, if you find any special characters in between words you can add  splitChars

Comment: It seems like I need some different way for this task, your code splits requested url string in outputList, but I'm trying to get search result as described in last edit,   please check

Comment: note sure this helps checked the source and found all results are wrapped around rc class, but this could be changed by search engine any time  besides now this code reads text rather innerhtml.

Comment: `foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='rc']"))` throws `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` and `foreach (HtmlNode item in nodes)` results is `test2`